# How to prevent zero from inserting in database?

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli

I am using mysqli and when I insert in my database everything seem so fine except for that if the row is null it is being inserted by zero (0) instead of leaving it blank. How can I solve this? What is the reason why it is displayed by zero instead of blank?

This is how it look like in my database :

```
id      ref_number    amount
1       143545646     3456
2       13545646       0
3       12324343       0
```

and this is what I like to display :

```
 id   ref_number   amount
 1    143545646    3456
 2    13545646         
 3    12324343
```

it must just leave blank if there is no amount or the value of amount is null.

Here is my code for inserting:

```
$sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_detail (`transaction_id`,`ref_number`,`amount`)
          VALUES ('$transaction_id','$ref_number',$amount) ";

    $query = $conn->query($sql);
```

If there is no amount, this is supposed to be blank but instead it displayed zero (0).

Comment: maybe your database field type is set to INT.

Comment: why did you guys downvote my question? if you want  don't clearly understand,then ask me? Sorry if i'm not good in english

Comment: @OlaitanMayowa :  if so what should I do? Isn't it right if I am talking amount my datatype should me int?

Comment: can you confirm if the data field type is INT?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Probably, data type of the field is INT NOT NULL. Datatype INT cannot be blank like Varchar/char/text.

to Prevent, You can alter your table and do accept null values, and at the time of retrieval you can handle null values using [`IFNULL`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull) function.

**EDIT**

```
ALTER TABLE `table` MODIFY `column` INT NULL;
```

**EDIT 2**

```
SELECT IFNULL(amount, 'what ever value you like') amount FROM transaction_detail;
```

**EDIT 3**

You may check amount in php that it's greater than zero.

```
$amount = (int) $amount;
if($amount > 0){
    $sql = "INSERT INTO transaction_detail (`transaction_id`,`ref_number`,`amount`)
          VALUES ('$transaction_id','$ref_number',$amount) ";

        $query = $conn->query($sql);
}
```

Comment: did you altered your table to accept null values ? are you getting null values ? if yes - `IFNULL` will work! - see the link to mysql docs in my answer.

Comment: how can I alter my table to accept null values? can you give example?

Comment: can you give example on how can I use IFNULL?

Comment: answer added respectively, you may found it more explanation over [docs](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/control-flow-functions.html#function_ifnull)

Comment: how about if I want to trap that it will not insert if the value is zero? how could I possibly do that?

Comment: you can compare the value in php, see updated answer